# Integer word problem disagreement

Tags: integers, word-problem

The word problem: Two friends owe me \$20. One friend owes me \$5 more than the other. How much does each friend owe me?

My equation:   $y + y + 5 = 20$

My colleague's:  $-y + -y+5 = 20$

I understand that we commonly use the - sign for owing money. But if your answers end up being -\$12.50 and the other -\$7.50, you can't owe a negative amount of money, right? You'd have to keep everything positive, and then state that "each owes \$7.50 and \$12.50, respectively", right? Or am I off on this?

Comment: Note that dollar signs carry specific meaning to formatting on this site. If you actually want a dollar sign (and also not mess up your text), you need to type `\$`.

Comment: I believe your colleague should've put the "minus" sign in front of $\$5$ and $\$20$. All those figures represent debt, so if they want to represent debt by negative numbers, they can keep $y$ positive (and use $-y$ for the actual debt) but then it needs to be done consistently. This would yield the equation $(-y)+(-y)+(-5)=(-20)$, which is equivalent to yours.

Comment: "*you can't owe a negative amount of money*"  Sure you can.

Comment: It's silly that your colleague didn't put a minus sign for the $ \$ 20 $ in his equation, as StinkingBishop says, @MichaelJohnson .

Comment: @JMoravitz , but how ? As a debt ?

Comment: @Spectre a negative debt is sometimes referred to as a positive "*credit*"... but just because there exists an alternate way of referring to something such that the values involved are all positive doesn't mean that using negative values is inherently wrong.

Comment: @JMoravitz, then the RHS should also be negative , right ?